# How to achieve whats app animation where toolbar disappear when scroll down and tabs stick to top?

Tags: react-native

I want to achieve something like whatsapp animation where toolbar is hidden during scroll down and show back when scroll up with the tab bar always sticking to the top so far i used Animated to set the toolbar height to 0 when scroll down and back to normal when scroll up but the problem is when the toolbar is hidden the scrollview height is changed to cover the area and that triggers the onscroll as well so i get that weird animation where toolbar keeps showing and hiding multiple times.

**Whats App Animation**

[image]

This is what I've tried so far

**Toolbar**

```
<Animated.View style={{height: this.state._showHeaderTitle}}>
    <ToolbarAndroid
        titleColor={'#FFF'}
        title={this.props.title}
        navIcon={images.arrowBack}
        onIconClicked={() => this._goBack()}
        onActionSelected={() => {}}
        actions={[{title: 'Search', icon: images.search, show: 'always'}]}
        style={[{backgroundColor: '#528eff', width: this.windowWidth, height: 48}]}/>
</Animated.View>
```

**ScrollView**

```
<ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}
    onScroll={(event) => this.detectScrollPosition(event)}
    style={{height: this.windowHeight - this.state.headerTitleCurrentHeight, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
        <View
            style={[styles.highNormalLowDocListBody]}>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.documents}
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    renderRow={(rowData) => this._renderRow(rowData)}
                />
        </View>
</ScrollView>
```

**onScroll**

```
detectScrollPosition(event) {
    var currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    var direction = currentOffset > this.state.offset ? 'down' : 'up';

    this.setState({offset: currentOffset});

    console.log('Begin Scroll');

    if (direction === 'up') {
        Animated.spring(this.state._showHeaderTitle, {
            toValue: 48,
            velocity: 6
        }).start();
        this.setState({headerTitleCurrentHeight: 48});
    } else {
        Animated.spring(this.state._showHeaderTitle, {
            toValue: 0,
            velocity: 6
        }).start();
        this.setState({headerTitleCurrentHeight: 0});
    }
};
```

Comment: Go through material design in android.  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: Look into `CoordinateLayout` some examples: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: You have to work on this.<https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/>.

Comment: @Beyond .. I think you should not have tagged `android` as its primarily related to React Native UI . Answers/suggestion you will get will be most likely native android in my opiinion

Comment: @cjmling I guess you are right but some of the comments here directed me to this https://github.com/Neson/react-native-android-design-support
as some one mentioned CoordinatorLayout which got me to that when i googled it along with react native so somehow it got me somewhere.

Comment: @BeyondProgramming cool . This feature looks nice. Trying to code in my existing app too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your contribution your comments lead me to search for CoordinatorLayout and eventually i found this GitHub Repo which totally made my day it's in Chinese though for those who don't know Chinese like me google translate will be enough to get you going

**GitHub:** https://github.com/maolion/mao-rn-android-kit

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoordinatorLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout for this purpose.

Below are some links you can refer :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html

http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Answer (score 0):

that is a new android xml block from the design and support library.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/tb_app_bar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:elevation="4dip"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

to use this you need to have the CoordinatorLayout and a NestedScrollView or recyclerview with a layout behavior

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

in the CollapsingToolbarLayout there is given how it must behave. 
now it is set to collapse and reappear when scrolled down.

Comment: The OP is asking about react native

Answer (score 0):

I think **react-native-animated-screen** should do exactly what you need

Check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-screen

[image]